Pass generic type T through withCheckedContinuation
I have a search for multiple types, so the general search method has a generic type T, and multiple simple methods call it specifying the type as needed. I'd like to delay search method's start (debounce in Combine) and I'd like to hide this code as deep as I can.
I'm generally using async/await API in my project, only using Combine if I have to. I didn't find a built-in solution for this using async/await so I'm gonna use Combine's debounce. (Please let me know if there is a cleaner solution without Combine)
So I have to go from async/await to Combine and back. This requires to use withCheckedContinuation which loses the T and causes an error:
// simple generic specification using Event
func searchEvents(query: String) async -> [Event] {
    await search(query: query)
}

// simple generic specification using Artist
func searchArtists(query: String) async -> [Artist] {
    await search(query: query)
}

// debouncing layer between specifications and generic search
private func search<T>(query: String) async -> [T] where T: Codable, T: Identifiable  {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        Debouncer().debounce(query) { query in
            Task {
                // Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
                let a = await self.performSearch(query: query) // <- error here
                continuation.resume(returning: a)
            }
        }
    }
}

// generic search function, details don't matter
private func performSearch<T>(query: String) async -> [T] where T: Codable, T: Identifiable {
    ...
}

// class performing simple debouncing
class Debouncer {

    static var shared = Debouncer()

    private var debounceSubscription: AnyCancellable?

    func debounce(_ string: String, block: (String) -> ()) {
        debounceSubscription?.cancel()
        debounceSubscription = Just(string)
            .debounce(for: .milliseconds(200), scheduler: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
            .sink { string in
                block(string)
            }
    }
}

Is there an elegant way to make it auto-understand the type without passing it as a parameter (type: T.Type, query: String)?
EDIT: Yeah, this thing doesn't work anyway. In the end I had to use Combine on a TextField itself like this:
    .onChange(query) { query in
        queryPublisher.send(query)
    }
    .onReceive(queryPublisher.debounce(for: .milliseconds(500), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)) { query in
        Task {
            options = await fetchOptions(query)
        }
    }

I wanted to avoid this because there are a lot of text fields using search in the app, but creating a base class for them is easier than hiding debounce deeper I guess. Thanks everyone for the wonderful suggestions, and for the fix with generics which I now know how to use!

Async Algorithms have debounce

That having been said, there are tons of problems with Debouncer. He’s not using his singleton, thereby creating a new one each time. This is not a good use case for singleton, anyway. The whole pattern of “cancel & recreate” is antithetical to debounce. This just won’t work as intended. Etc. @f3dm76, if you’re interested in feedback regarding that, let us know. I think it is unrelated to the question at hand, namely, resolving type inference.

@Rob I only mentioned it because the OP said they prefer async/await and are only using combine because of debounce.

Tell the compiler that performSearch will return an array of T
let a: [T] = await performSearch(query: query)

Now T in performSearch will be the same as T in search which the compiler can conclude what type it is.

Thank you! I knew I was missing something simple) I tried let a = await performSearch(query: query) as! [T], it didn't work and I gave up

Joakim is correct (+1). For the sake of completeness, there is another option: Instead of assigning it to a local variable, you could invoke it directly as a parameter of resume, at which point the compiler can infer the return type:
continuation.resume(
    returning: await self.performSearch(query: query)
)

When you assign it to an intermediate local variable, as in your original sample, that is just one step too far for the compiler to infer the return type.

You said:

I’m generally using async/await API in my project, only using Combine if I have to. I didn't find a built-in solution for this using async/await so …

As lorem ipsum said, you can use Swift Async Algorithms to debounce an asynchronous sequence, such as an AsyncChannel. For example:
import SwiftUI
import AsyncAlgorithms

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    private let channel = AsyncChannel<String>()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Input", text: $text)
            .task(id: text) {
                await channel.send(text)
            }
            .task {
                for await string in channel.debounce(for: .milliseconds(200)) {
                    …
                }
            }
    }
}

Or, if you would like to “hide this code as deep as I can”, you can theoretically wrap this logic in an separate object:
actor Debouncer<T: Sendable> {
    private let channel = AsyncChannel<T>()

    func onUpdate(duration: Duration = .milliseconds(200), block: @escaping @Sendable (T) -> Void) async throws {
        for try await value in channel.debounce(for: duration) {
            block(value)
        }
    }

    func send(_ value: T) async {
        await channel.send(value)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    private let debouncer = Debouncer<String>()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Input", text: $text)
            .task(id: text) {
                await debouncer.send(text)
            }
            .task {
                try? await debouncer.onUpdate { string in
                    …
                }
            }
    }
}


If you do not want to introduce the Swift Async Algorithms dependency into your project, it is not hard to write one’s own async-await debouncer using unstructured concurrency. You can just save the Task in a property, e.g., previousTask, and then make sure when you send a new value, cancel the previous one:
actor Debouncer<T: Sendable> {
    let duration: Duration

    private var previousTask: Task<Void, Never>?

    init(duration: Duration = .milliseconds(200)) {
        self.duration = duration
    }

    func send(_ value: T, block: @escaping @Sendable (T) -> Void) async {
        previousTask?.cancel()

        let task = Task {
            do {
                try await Task.sleep(for: duration)
                block(value)
            } catch {
                // this is intentionally blank
            }
        }

        previousTask = task

        return await withTaskCancellationHandler {
            _ = await task.value
        } onCancel: {
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    private let debouncer = Debouncer<String>()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Input", text: $text)
            .task(id: text) {
                await debouncer.send(text) { string in
                    print("processing", string)
                }
            }
    }
}

As you can see, there are many possible variations on the theme, so do not get lost in the details. But, in short, there is no reason to introduce Combine simply for debouncing behaviors.
